# Import csvfile into mongoDB at real time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend, web-development-server

How do I automatically import new/incoming .csv files from a folder through a server into mlab (at real time , not in cmd line)? How do I use it in an Express.js project?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? I need to do the same!